# I am a hidden dictator

Tags: riddle

What am I?
Try to guess with this short riddle:

> I am a hidden dictator,
>
> I am in control,
>
> You will follow me blindly,
>
> and you will feel like the happiest of all.

Comment: Why is this puzzle being downvoted?

Comment: @MikeQ Perhaps because it's lacking something unique to make a specific and single answer. Considering there are multiple answers that have been given that fit the riddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps its:

> your heart

I am a hidden dictator,

> the heart is an organ inside your body, hidden under the skin, sometimes characterized as having "hidden desires"

I am in control,

> emotions (especially raw) can dictate actions and decision making

You will follow me blindly,

> some people are said to follow their heart blindly

and you will feel like the happiest of all.

> pursuit of what you love tends to make people happy

Comment: I was looking for the word "love", but this answer is pretty much the same.

Comment: @HugoWoesthuis Why is love a hidden dictator?

Comment: @MikeQ it was actually ment as a filler, but thinking about it...

Comment: @HugoWoesthuis I was contemplating between brain and heart as well, but settled on heart because everyone knows the brain controls the body, but I took hidden dictator to be the thing that controls the brain, to which my answer is the heart. In intense emotions, people dont usually do what is logical, but what they desire to do based on their feelings. i associate brain with logic and heart with feelings (although yes, the brain processes feelings etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You could be a

> Brain

`I am a hidden dictator`

> The brain is inside the skull, and not visible from the outside.

`I am in control`

> Your brain controls your feelings, voluntary actions, and a large portion of your nervous system.

`You will follow me blindly`

> You can't see your own brain, since your eyes point outward. Or, this could mean that when your brain decides to do something, you will (typically) do it.

`and you will feel like the happiest of all.`

> Happiness is an emotion. The [amygdala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amygdala) is a portion of the brain that manages emotions.

Comment: Although this answer is very good, it is not the answer I am looking for. Although the real answer has something to do with brains and mentality.

Answer (score 1):

You're:

> Lust / desire

I am a hidden dictator,

> It's well hidden

I am in control,

> For the weak-minded

You will follow me blindly,

> You follow your desire / lust

and you will feel like the happiest of all.

> Sure